# Ambiguous use of 'convertPoint'

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, swift, interop

I'm in the midst of trying to learn both Swift and Cocoa at the same time. I have a subclass of NSView (actually of NSControl). In this subclass, I am trying to run the following line:

```
self.convertPoint(aPoint: NSPoint(0.0, 0.0), fromView: self)
```

When I have this line in my code, I get the error message:

> Ambiguous use of 'convertPoint'

It looks like in Cocoa, there are two overloaded convertPoint methods with the exact same type signature I'm trying to use here. How do I resolve this ambiguity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two things that you need to fix:

1. The fix for "Ambiguous use of `convertPoint`" is simply to remove the `aPoint:` parameter name:

   ```
   self.convertPoint(NSPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0), fromView: self)
   ```
2. In contrast, `NSPoint`'s initializer needs to include its property names:

   ```
   NSPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
   ```

   You can actually see this by attempting to create a stand-alone `var` for your `NSPoint` like so:

   ```
   var p = NSPoint(0.0, 0.0)
   ```

   It'll give you the error: "Missing argument labels `x:y:` in call"

Comment: Oops, I wasn't actually passing in an empty point here - I'm passing in a point from a mouseMoved event. If you don't mind explaining, why does aPoint: make the method call ambiguous?

Comment: It looks like it's just a poor error from Xcode (although I can't be 100% sure offhand). What really seems to be going on is the fact functions in Swift don't use the name of the first parameter in their calls.